# その巨人の腹をかっさいた manga sentence

Tags: translation, manga

The complete sentence is this:

ハンジは仲間を喰った

その巨人の腹をかっさいた

I can't really understand the meaning, why is it ハンジは istead of ハンジの？

Then we have 腹をかっさいた.
腹 means stomach while かっさい means to cheer, to make an ovation?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It needs to be ハンジは and not ハンジの because it is the subject that performed the two actions described --- 「[仲間]{なかま}を[喰]{く}った」 and 「その[巨人]{きょじん}の[腹]{はら}をかっさいた」.

「その巨人」 refers to the 「仲間」.

「かっさいた」 ＝ 「かっ裂いた」 = "ripped open" said in the animated tough guy language using 「かっ」, a verb prefix for that purpose.

"Haiji ate his friend.  He ripped open the giant's abdomen."

For your reference, other emphatic verb prefixes include 「おっ」、「つっ」、「とっ」、「ひっ」、「ぶっ」、「ぶん」, etc.  Unfortunately, these are rarely interchangeable.  I will not get into that here, though.

Comment: I haven't seen/read 進撃の巨人 (which I am assuming this is from...) but is it not possible that it could be `ハンジは【仲間を喰ったその巨人】の腹をかっさいた`? Slicing a stomach seems like something that might be done in revenge for having your friend eaten...

Comment: @Hyperworm That would be more than just possible.  Lines from manga can be difficult to decipher without the drawings AND punctuations.

Comment: @TokyoNagoya Then maybe ハンジは仲間を喰ったその巨人の腹をかっさいた is one sentence, like "Hanji ripped open the abdomen of the giant who ate his(=Hanji's) friends", no?

Comment: @Chocolate Yes!  That would make more sense even though I am unfamiliar with the story.

Comment: @TokyoNagoya Yes I was considering already Hanji was the one who ripped the stomach of the titans. Anyway there wasn't any puntuaction, the sentece was written exactly like this.